# How do I turn off/change the log level of dozer during unit tests with standard java logging?

Tags: java, testing, logging, junit, dozer

We are using dozer, and every time a test runs it will create an instance of the dozer mapping (or so it looks, I'm not a hard core dozer guy). This gives a lot of junk in the console when running unit tests (see below). How do we turns this off? Completely off.

We're using Maven as build tool, so a property file would be preferable. I have tried to load logging.properties without any luck (we're also using java.util.logging.Logger)

I have tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533227/how-can-i-disable-the-default-console-handler-while-using-the-java-logging-api) (using programmatic approach), but we have many tests so added to all of them is close to impossible.

*Any tips/tricks is much appreciated!*

Example of the output - line numbers run into thousands, which makes the build slow:

> 2640 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Trying to find xml mapping file: dozerServicesEjb/dozerBeanMapper.xml
>
> 2642 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Using URL [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/dozerBeanMapper.xml] to load custom xml mappings
>
> 2654 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Successfully loaded custom xml mappings from URL: [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/dozerBeanMapper.xml]
>
> 2654 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Trying to find xml mapping file: dozerServicesEjb/AccountArrangementMapping.xml
>
> 2655 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Using URL [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/AccountArrangementMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
>
> 2683 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Successfully loaded custom xml mappings from URL: [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/AccountArrangementMapping.xml]
>
> 2684 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Trying to find xml mapping file: dozerServicesEjb/AddressMapping.xml
>
> 2685 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Using URL [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/AddressMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
>
> 2697 [main] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Successfully loaded custom xml mappings from URL: [file:/C:/development/core-services/services.ejb/target/classes/dozerServicesEjb/AddressMapping.xml]
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

Put a `log4j.properties` file in `src/test/resources` that disables the `org.dozer` logger.

```
log4j.logger.org.dozer=OFF
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working - am I doing something wrong? I simply added the file log4j.properties to src/test/resources with the property you mentioned, but it continues to logs the same amount. I didn't have log4j as dependency, so I added it - but still the same.

Comment: ah, so if you didn't have log4j previously there must be another logging mechanism in use. I am not sure what that is.

Comment: Thanks anyway - I'm pretty sure that changing the log4j would work, but since I'm not using log4j this doesn't seem to be working...