# How to turn off Dozer logging entries in log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j2, dozer

How to turn off Dozer logging entries in log4j2 ?
Using Java 1.8,  Dozer version: 6.4.1, Logger version 2.11.2 on Windows 7
pom.xml config :

```xml
   <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
   <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
```

Every time I load a web page or run a JUnit tests Dozer logs 100s of lines of logging messages which makes the application bit slow. Tried following configuration in log4j2.xml to turn off Dozer messages but it doesn't turn off Dozer INFO messages.

```xml
    <Configuration
        xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" status="WARN">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="basePath">../cabsys/logs</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <!-- File Appender -->
            <File name="FILE" fileName="${basePath}/cabsys_logfile.log"
                append="true">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
            </File>
            <!-- Console Appender -->
            <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
                <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="INFO" maxLevel="INFO"
                    onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            </Console>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="debug">
                <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
                <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
        
        <!-- categories --> 
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder">
            <priority value="OFF" />
        </category> 
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder">
            <priority value="OFF" />
        </category>
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver">
            <priority value="OFF" />
        </category>
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.util.RuntimeUtils">
            <priority value="OFF" />
        </category>
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.el.ELExpressionFactory">
        <priority value="OFF" />
        </category>
        <category name="com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver">
            <priority value="OFF" />
        </category>
    </Configuration>
```

Dozer Log entries :

`

```
13:14:52,284 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.util.RuntimeUtils] (default task-2) OSGi support is false
13:14:52,290 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:52,301 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:52,304 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:52,322 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.el.ELExpressionFactory] (default task-2) javax.el support is true
13:14:52,388 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,009 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,015 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,030 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:53,188 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:53,189 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:53,191 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:53,197 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,259 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,261 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,273 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:53,308 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:53,309 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:53,312 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:53,325 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,380 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,381 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,394 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:53,425 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:53,426 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:53,429 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:53,435 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,498 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,500 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,513 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:53,621 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:53,623 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:53,630 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:53,637 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,715 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,718 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,730 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:53,784 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:53,784 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:53,800 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:53,808 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:53,888 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,890 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:53,931 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:54,009 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:54,009 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:54,012 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:54,018 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:54,059 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,061 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,071 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:54,100 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:54,101 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:54,109 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:54,117 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:54,166 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,167 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,179 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:54,234 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:54,235 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:54,237 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:54,243 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:54,281 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,283 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,294 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:54,324 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:54,324 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:54,330 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:54,337 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:54,392 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,393 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,406 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
13:14:54,438 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder] (default task-2) Initializing Dozer. Version: 6.4.1, Thread Name: default task-2
13:14:54,438 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Trying to find Dozer configuration file: dozer.properties
13:14:54,442 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.config.resolvers.LegacyPropertiesSettingsResolver] (default task-2) Using URL [vfs:/D:/mh_stuff/E_drive/installed/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cabsys.war/WEB-INF/classes/dozer.properties] for Dozer settings
13:14:54,448 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Using URL [dozerBeanMapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
13:14:54,486 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Trying to resolve XML entity with public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,486 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.SchemaLSResourceResolver] (default task-2) Resolved public ID [null] and system ID [http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd]
13:14:54,495 INFO  [com.github.dozermapper.core.builder.xml.BeanMappingXMLBuilder] (default task-2) Successfully loaded custom xml mapping.
```

`

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tvaksa.cabsys</groupId>
    <artifactId>cabsys</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cabsys</name>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/cabsys</url>

    <properties>

        <!-- Dependency versions -->
        <log4j.version>2.11.2</log4j.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MapStruct Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dozer Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Logging utilty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF API & Impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- primefaces https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF utility library -> Omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This will get hamcrest-core automatically -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate 5.3.5.Final -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jboss-client.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <finalName>cabsys</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestions as how to turn off Dozer logging messages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logger for suppressing logs from a package and its subpackages. Under `Loggers` element, try adding below configuration -

```
        <Logger name="com.github.dozermapper" level="OFF" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>
```

Comment: I tried that `Loggers` before to supress logs but it's not working. Dozer keeps continuing to log the same amount of INFO entries. Between Dozer is using SLF4J framework. does that make any difference ?

Comment: Using logger to suppress unnecessary logs is an standard approach. Also, slf4j is just a wrapper. As per current configuration, dozer debug logs must be getting printed as well

Comment: Ah, am I doing something wrong ? I just want to turn OFF all Dozer logging entries, as it is causing the application slow to load with it's huge amount logging entries and all are INFO entries. I tried other SO answers like this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/27148614/10208183, but none of them working.

Comment: can you add generate logs as well in your question. One more thing, try setting  `level="WARN"` for the `root` logger and then see whether dozer logs are still getting printed or not.

Comment: Hi, Dozer keeps logging the same amount of INFO entries even with `level=WARN` for the `root` logger. I've updated the question with Dozer log entries.

Comment: It seems your application is not using this log4j2 configuration because the printed logs content is different than the pattern specified in appenders.

Comment: Also, once you set root logger level to WARN, no INFO logs should be printed as no other logger is configured in your config file.

Comment: When I set logger level to `WARN` all of my Application's `DEBUG` and `INFO` messages are not printed, but only Dozer `INFO` messages are printed and that's what the problem is.

Comment: it seems some other logging library is present in your application classpath. Can you check that or update dependencies listed in pom.xml in your question.

Comment: No, using only log4j2. Updated question with pom.