# Debug mode: Red messages are confusing me

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

It's the first time that I am using Java. So I have configured Tomcat in Intelij and ran the debug mode. The server gets startet and it looks like everything works but I am very confused about these red messages, because they look like errors but they're not:

[image: error]

I would like to have only the error messages displayed in red. Is there a way I could either deactivate those messages or give them another color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output goes to the `stderr` stream. IntelliJ IDEA allows to configure different colors for `stdout` and `stderr` streams in File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors, Console | **Error output**:

[image: stderr]

Comment: Thanks, that works and now the messages have another color but if I am not mistaking, now even the error messages have the same color. If so, that wasn't the goal, since the info messages that I receive are no errors.

Comment: @Ray Tomcat is using `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` in `conf/logging.properties` for the console output. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156206/104891), this logger prints to the `stderr` by design instead of `stdout`.