# IntelliJ Application log is always in red color

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi module maven spring boot java 11 application that runs okay and its logs are all the correct colors.

I created a new module that will run as a separate application, and is part of the multi module application.

But when I run this separate application its logs are all in red color like so:

[image: All logs are red for console]

I have tried deleting the module, invalidating caches, recreating it, but the problem persists.

Is there any way to fix this or is this a side effect from the weird setup I have going on?

I am running the project on IntellJ Ultimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java logger implementation shipped with JRE (`java.util.logging`) is logging to `System.err` by default (instead of `System.out`). Its red, because it is an error stream.

Comment: How can I configure it to log to System.out? I am using Lombok with @Log annotation.

Comment: Here is one example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954749/1527544 but it would be better to use something different for logging. My personal choice is a logback. http://logback.qos.ch/