# How to send different log levels to different files/outputs in Java logging?

Tags: java, logging

I am using Java Logging (not Log4j). I want to send logs of level INFO and below it to System.out, and WARNING and SEVERE to System.err. I believe it looks much nicer, because I can easily distinguish error from info and below it. Is there anyway to do that?

In general, it is possible to tell Logger to log message below a certain level. Bu default it goes higher than the specified level.

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23717493/6722100

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it looks much nicer, because I can easily distinguish error from info and below it. Is there anyway to do that?

As 'pruntlar' pointed out that is covered in: [How do I change java logging console output from std err to std out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194165/how-do-i-change-java-logging-console-output-from-std-err-to-std-out)

> In general, it is possible to tell Logger to log message below a certain level. By default it goes higher than the specified level.

Not out of the box.  You have to write a `Level` filter and install it on the `Logger` or `Handler`.