# Console Output Colour in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, remotewebdriver

I want print log each selenium code line in Eclipse console, so in `setUp()` I add a new line like this:

```
//import
import java.util.logging.Level;

//setup
driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

I successfully to printed a log on the console, but it is red.

[image: output console]

I know this is no error.

**Environment:**

- Mac
- Eclipse Photon 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Selenium-Java 3.5.3 (maven dependency)
- JUnit

Can I print black on the console ? is it possible ?

Comment: The logger is writing to 'standard error' which is displayed in red by Eclipse. You can change the standard error colour in the Eclipse Preferences in 'Run/Debug > Console'

Comment: Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194165/2670892) for changing the output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger is writing to 'standard error' which is displayed in red by Eclipse.

You can change the standard error colour in the Eclipse Preferences in 'Run/Debug > Console' (but this will change the colour for all standard error output).