# Log messages are not showing up in groovy jenkins script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, java.util.logging

I'm in need to extend my jenkins scripts with logging functionality and tried to use `java.util.logging` for this purpose. The following snippet shows what I already did.

```
import java.util.logging.*

@NonCPS
def tryLogging() {
        println("Start")
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Test")
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        ConsoleHandler handler = new java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter())
        logger.addHandler(handler)      
        logger.info("Hello")
        logger.severe("Severe")
        println("End")
}

tryLogging()
```

My console log now says the following:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
Start
[Pipeline] echo
End
```

There is really no visible log message and I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone here explain me how to make the console log visible? I'm also unsure if I have to use this `@NonCPS` here?

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConsoleHandler prints to System.err.  Modify your script to use

`System.err.println("Start")` and see if 'Start' still shows up in the console.  If it doesn't then the problem is the [ConsoleHandler is writing to a stream you can't see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194165/how-do-i-change-java-logging-console-output-from-std-err-to-std-out).

Another thing to change is that you'll want to [ensure your named logger can't be garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove).  Depending the Java version you are using the logger can be garbage collected and you can lose your attached handler.

> I'm also unsure if I have to use this @NonCPS here?

[What is @NonCPS annotation in Jenkins pipeline script](https://www.devopscat.tech/2018/10/what-is-noncps-in-jenkins-pipeline/) has information that you might find helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for the links. I already searched here, but one has to ask the right question. I'll now try if the solutions works for me.